# How to highlight text by changing background colour in Mail

Tags: mail.app

In Mail, I can only change the background of the entire email.

How do I do this just for highlighted text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to do this.  Here's how I do it.

- <kbd>⌘ + T</kbd>: to open up `Fonts` window
- click on the document background color icon and `Colors` window will open
- choose the highlight background color you desire note:

  - **Note**: this will change the background color of your *entire* email
- Select the text that you want highlighted and cut (<kbd>⌘ + X</kbd>)
- Go back to `Colors` window and change background color of entire email back to original color (usually white).
- Paste (<kbd>⌘ + V</kbd>) the text back into email, and you will see the text with your desired background color

Comment: Seriously ridiculous that apple doesn't allow you to change background color of selected text any other way...

Comment: This is hillarious and it works! :)

Comment: not working for me on macOS Sierra

Comment: for me it works on macOS Sierra